# App crashes with IndexOutOfBoundsException when deleting firebase child with removeValue()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am making an android app based on **firebase Realtime database**. I am reading the data in a `RecyclerView`. There are three items in my `RecyclerView`.

1. Text view = Name
2. Text view = Number
3. Button = Delete

When I delete some child from my `RecyclerView` three things can happen:

1. Sometimes it deletes the targeted child normally
2. Sometimes it deletes some other child (often which is below the targeted child.)
3. Sometimes my app crashes.

This is the code for my adapter:

```
public class holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public Button btnDelete;
    public TextView tvName;
    public TextView tvRoll;

    public holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        btnDelete=(Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idDelete);
        tvName=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idName);
        tvRoll=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idRoll);

    }
}
```

This is the code to show items in recycler view and code for delete button:

```
options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<basic>()
                .setQuery(myRef, basic.class)
                .build();
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<basic, holder>(options) {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull holder holder, final int i, @NonNull final basic basic) {
                holder.tvName.setText(basic.getFb01name());
                holder.tvRoll.setText(basic.getFb04roll());
                holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            myRef.child(getRef(i).getKey()).removeValue();
                    }
                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items, parent, false);
                return new holder(v);
            }
        };
        //------------------------------
        adapter.startListening();
        Userlist.setAdapter(adapter);
        //-----------------------------------
```

I cannot guess where is the problem.

Please also provide a practical solution.

This is the crash report:

```
2020-11-30 23:27:45.968 10796-10796/com.my App Name E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.my App Name, PID: 10796
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.getSnapshot(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:70)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getRef(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:112)
        at com.my App Name.ViewActivity$1$1.onClick(ViewActivity.java:72)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2020-11-30 23:27:46.701 1467-10685/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox E/sb.v.u.LiteSuggestSourc: On-device lite suggest model loading error.
2020-11-30 23:27:46.818 1467-1774/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox E/MDD: DownloadProgressMonitor: Can't find file group for uri: android://com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/files/sharedminusonemodule/shared/SharedMinusOneData.pb.tmp
```

Comment: Replace `myRef.child(getRef(i).getKey()).removeValue()` with `getRef(i).removeValue()`. I don't think it'll fix the problem (I would've posted it as an answer otherwise), but it's more idiomatic and less likely to cause race conditions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You helped promptly as always. But I am sorry to say that the above amendment did not work. Could you take pains to rethink about it?

Comment: Can you share the rash report

Comment: @ Zain I have added the crash report.

Comment: Thanks. Can you share this method `getRef(i)` .. it seems that it has some issues

Comment: My firebase reference is like this:       `myRef = myfire.getReference().child("Users").child("GcZoeK7JIbNWVOog6ZjUPiBfxwn2");`

Comment: can you elaborate more how can you use `i` when you pass it to `getRef(i) ` ?

Comment: @ Zain I have no idea about that. I followed a tutorial and used `i` in my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225332/discussion-between-zain-and-user14253444).

Comment: Hey @Zain. The `getRef()` is a method in the FirebaseUI adapters that returns a `DatabaseReference` for the item that is at position `i` in the adapter. Code: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java#L114-L116

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks so much .. a bit since I touched Firebase .. much appreciated for your usual and thoughtful info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that when you access Firebase `getRef(i)` within the button `onClick` callback, it can reference a wrong position `i` causing `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

So, we'll get the key outside of the callback as below:

```
options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<basic>()
            .setQuery(myRef, basic.class)
            .build();
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<basic, holder>(options) {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull holder holder, final int i, @NonNull final basic basic) {
            holder.tvName.setText(basic.getFb01name());
            holder.tvRoll.setText(basic.getFb04roll());
            String refKey = getRef(i).getKey(); // <<<<<< Here is the change
            
            holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myRef.child(refKey)).removeValue();
                }
            });
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items, parent, false);
            return new holder(v);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Zain for a practical solution.